# Написать текст по дуге окружности

Tags: html, css

Есть макет, на котором слова вокруг написаны как-бы на окружности, от чего текст не просто прямой, а с внутренним углом. Вопрос, как такое сделать с помощью html и css ? Пока единственное что пришло в голову, это отпозиционировать отдельно каждую букву, но этот метод кажется совсем не практичным ...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Готовое решение с раскладом по буквам хорошо описано тут https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр отлично. Напишите в ответы, я галочку поставлю.

Comment: Лучше в таких случаях использовать не костыли, а нормальные решения. Я бы посоветовал svg

Comment: @sepgg что-то я не припомню текстовых трансформаций по кривой в svg. Да, там возможностей больше для текста.

Comment: @sepgg там есть матричные трансформации, но по дуге матрицей помоему не выйдет - хотя возможно ошибаюсь, этот вопрос может разъяснить кто-то ещё)

Comment: решение однозначно есть, первое что пришло в голову - https://jsfiddle.net/yu6kmL9e/

Comment: @sepgg да, действительно. Добавь плиз ответ. И ссылка на эту фичу в MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath

Comment: @sepgg Отлично. ТО что нужно. Правда переменив все значения, так и не понял, как увеличить расстояние между словами ?

Comment: css2  text{ letter-spacing: 10px /*между буквами*/;  word-spacing: 10px; /*между словами*/} https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/letter-spacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В CSS пока нету встроенных возможностей для трансформации текста по кривой. Но есть плагин jQuery [Lettering](http://letteringjs.com/), который разбивает текст по буквам. После разбивки можно применять трансформацию css по-буквенно:

```
.char1 { transform: rotate(6deg); }
.char2 { transform: rotate(12deg); }
.char3 { transform: rotate(18deg); }
```

Центр вращения должен быть один для всех букв в слове, и должен быть смещён вниз, чтобы сделать текст "по дуге". Как сделать, с примером - подробно [описано тут](https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/).